# What's a calling thread?

Tags: multithreading, android-camera2

I am using CameraAPI2 of Android for app development.

I use the `setOnImageAvailableListener(OnImageAvailableListener listener, Handler handler)` to specify a callback or a listener.
The argument `listener` is a callback that will be run and the argument `handler` specifies the `Thread` the listener should be invoked on. If the handler is `null`, the listener should be invoked on the calling thread's looper.

The listener is an interface and its `onImageAvailable()` method should be overridden.

I am not quite clear what is the "calling thread". Is it the thread calling the `setOnImageAvailableListener(...)` method or the thread calling the `onImageAvailable(...)` method?

Answer (score 3):

A *calling thread* is the thread that calls a method or the thread inside which a method is called. If `thread1` calls method `methodA` (if `methodA` gets called from within `thread1`) then the calling thread of `methodA` is `thread1`. The *listener* argument specifies a callback method that will be called later in time. The calling thread will be the thread that calls the `onImageAvailable` method (the thread from which the call originated).

As per the [official docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html), the callbacks are delivered to the thread that makes the call to `Camera.open`.

Comment: I go into the source code of setOnImageAvailableListener(...) located in ImageReader.java :( ...Looper looper = handler != null ? handler.getLooper() : Looper.myLooper();...) I think the calling thread should the thread that calls setOnImageAvailableListener(...)

Comment: The source code states that the `listener` variable is **only** assigned, not call dispatched. Hence, `setOnImageAvailableListener` **does not call** `listener`, which basically means it does not call the `onImageAvailable` callback. Therefore you can't say that the call to the callback originated from within this method and hence, cannot state that the calling thread is the **same** as the one that calls `setOnImageAvailableListener`.

Comment: The callbacks are delivered to the thread that makes the call to `Camera.open`, as per the [official docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html)

Comment: The document is about the old API and I use camera2 now.